# PowerShell - How to execute BAT (batch) command on specific file? (Concatenate path and command and propagate arguments )

Tags: powershell, batch-file, robotframework

I need to execute in PowerShell 5 some **robot** (RobotFramework) batch file on specific robot file.
Simple usage by documentation is: "robot file.robot" which works but in the PowerShell script I am having issues.
I defined:

```
$ROBOT_PATH="C:\Program Files\Robot\Scripts"
```

But when trying to execute:

```
$ROBOT_PATH\robot.bat User.robot
```

Getting an Error: `Unexpected token '\robot.bat' in expression or statement.`

If I try:
`"$ROBOT_PATH\robot.bat" User.robot`  or   `"$ROBOT_PATH\robot.bat" "User.robot"`  then getting: Unexpected `token '"User.robot"' in expression or statement.`

So how to concatenate **Path** and **Command** and propagate **Arguments** for that command?
Important thing to emphasize is that I should not first do the "**cd** to PATH" before executing the command. If I do the **"cd"** then it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the path to a string like this

```
& "${ROBOT_PATH}\robot.bat" User.robot
```

To re-enable the variable substitution you have to use the curly brackets.

Comment: Unforutanley again I am getting error 

Unexpected token 'User.robot' in expression or statement.

PS C:\Projects\FA> "${ROBOT_PATH}\robot.bat" User.robot
At line:1 char:27
+ "${ROBOT_PATH}\robot.bat" User.robot
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'User.robot' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo  ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

PS C:\Projects\FA> dir

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----

-a----         5/4/2020   7:14 PM           1470 User.robot

Comment: @AndreyDonald put `User.robot` in `-argumentlist "User.robot"`

Comment: @harper I tried your example but it still does not work :-( 
Is it maybe because there is blank space in "Program Files"


`$ROBOT_PATH="C:\Program Files\FIS\Testing Services\Test Framework\Robot Framework\Scripts"`

`"${ROBOT_PATH}\robot.bat" User.robot`

`Unexpected token 'User.robot' in expression or statement.`

Comment: @harper thank you very much for your feedback it worked - I marked it as ANSWER.     If I may ask you just one more question - I am trying to invoke this PowerShell script from external system (Octopus Deployment platform) as inline PowerShell code , but not directly from the PowerShell terminal. And now I am still facing issue that I cannot run it. Do you by any chance can guess why I cannot invoke it in exactly the same manner. In the log I do not see any much useful info: `At C:\Octopus\Script.ps1:44 char:1 
Error
+ & "${ROBOT_PATH}\robot.bat" -d $REPORT_PATH -v adsName:$ADS_SERVER -i`

Comment: @AndreyDonald The idea of StackOverflow is to have a question by itself. You have an additional question. Feel free to ask everybody (not me alone) to help with the second question. You have more possibilities there to describe you problem than you have in the comment.